# Display file contents if it has corresponding line number

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, awk

I have two files in the following format:

```
File A
4
5
8
9

File B
1 text
2 text1
3 text2
4 text3
5 text4
6 text5
7 text6
8 text7
9 text8
```

What I want to have for my output is just the following (the second field in File B if it corresponds to the line number in File A):

```
test3
test4
text7
text8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple `sed` script from the file A by appending `p` to each line, then run the script in another `sed` with `-n` not to print the other lines. Moreover, there's no need to save the generated script, you can pipe it between the `sed`s:

```
sed 's/$/p/' A | sed -nf- B
```

Comment: Pardon my newness, but why are we using 'p' and can you explain what second sed statement is doing?

Comment: `p` means "print". `-n` means "don't print unless told to". `-f-` means "read the script from the standard input".

Comment: How does it know to print? Does it look by default if the first field is same in both files?

Comment: @user3299633: No, a number before `p` stands for the line number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1];next;} FNR in seen' FileA FileB
text3
text4
text7
text8
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{seen[$1];next;}`

  While reading the first file, this adds each number as a keey to the associative array `seen`.

  FNR is the line number of the current file and NR is the line number among all lines read.  So when `FNR==NR`, then we are still reading the first file, `FileA` in this case.  `seen[$1]` creates a key in `seen` with value `$1`.  `next` tells awk to skip the rest of the commands and start over on the next line.
- `FNR in seen`

  While reading the second file, this prints any line if its line number is in `seen`.

  `FNR in seen` is a condition.  It evaluates to true if the line number FNR is a key in array `seen`.  Since we have specified no action for this condition, the default action is taken which is to print the line.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a relational "join" operation, so use the standard UNIX `join` command:

```
$ join fileA.txt fileB.txt
4 text3
5 text4
8 text7
9 text8
```

To only get the second field from the second file, add `-o 2.2`:

```
$ join -o 2.2 fileA.txt fileB.txt
text3
text4
text7
text8
```

Both files needs to be sorted on the join field (the first column in this example) for this to work.

Cheers!